# QString::arg() adjust size of variable and remove blank spaces

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore

I have such code piece

```
   QString day= ui->direct_pow_lineEdit_1->text();
   QString hour = ui->direct_pow_lineEdit_2->text();
   QString minute = ui->direct_pow_lineEdit_3->text();
   QString destIP = QString("010.000.000.001");
   QString data_to_transfer = QString("450%1015%2%3%4").arg(day,2).arg(destIP).arg(hour,2).arg(minute,2);
```

what I would like to haveis Qt equivalent of `sprintf(data_to_transfer, "450%02s015%s%02s%02s", day, destIP, hour, minute )`  but

```
  QDebug deb = qDebug();
   deb << data_to_transfer;
```

outputs

```
450 215 1010.000.000.001 1
```

how can I correctly modify a QString and I don't want to remove blank spaces between the variables?

**EDIT:**

blank spaces are due to the default value, if I define `.arg(day,2,'0')` then it fills with 0 instead of the blank space. however, if there is no blank space, QString is not edited properly. For example

```
`QString data_to_transfer = QString("450%1015%2").arg(day, 2, '0').arg(destIP, 2, '0');`
```

outputs "450010.000.000.0011531" where day is 31

**SOLUTION:**

This one solved my problem, but I would appreciate to see a better solution.

```
QString data_to_transfer = QString("450%1").arg(day,2,'0');
data_to_transfer.append("015");
data_to_transfer.append(destIP);
data_to_transfer.append(QString("%1").arg(hour,2,'0'));
data_to_transfer.append(QString("%1").arg(minute,2,'0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QString data_to_transfer = QString().sprintf("450%02s%015%s%02s%02s",
day.toUtf8().constData(),
destIP.toUtf8().constData(),
hour.toUtf8().constData(),
minute.toUtf8().constData());
```

Comment: I get such output 450 1%015010.000.000.001 2 3 for the day =1 , hour = 2, minute = 3. am I doing something wrong? I enter the value on a qeditline

Comment: it was my mistake that I forgot to write s after %01, but I still have blank spaces, how can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

[QString::arg() is greedy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg): It takes up to two digits to make up the id. This is what your call looks like to QString:

> QString("450 **%10** 15 **%2** **%3** **%4**")

(Spaces added for readability.)

So the first %n is actually the highest (=10) and gets assigned the arg()  value of `minute`.
To overcome this, use two-digit counters:

```
QString("450%01015%02%03%04")
```